# Put On Term Limits

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the correctness of the phrase "***put on***" in this [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/17/us/politics/as-trump-embraces-term-limits-allies-in-congress-pull-away.html?rref=politics&module=Ribbon&version=context&region=Header&action=click&contentCollection=Politics&pgtype=Multimedia) article:

> “We’re going to ***put on*** term limits, which a lot of people aren’t happy about, but we’re ***putting on*** term limits,” Mr. Trump said in an interview with “60 Minutes” that aired Sunday. “We’re doing a lot of things to clean up the system.”

"***Put on*** term limits" probably means to have term limits in place.  But, I cannot find a definition of "***put on***" that would fit this usage.  Could it be a error in the article?

Comment: When people speak, they don't consult a dictionary first. However, this is an unremarkable use of the verb _put,_ and since it comprises only a single syllable, it is prominent in this particular speaker's lexicon.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - yes, the scare use of a dictionary  appears to be a widespread problem.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Is there something frightening about the dictionary? I am baffled by your comment, but intrigued.

Answer (score 2):

***[To put on](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+on)***  here means :

> - ***to impose as a burden*** or levy: *to put a tax on cars.*

(Collins Dictionary)

- Trump is saying that they  will impose term limits.

Comment: Another plausible meaning is putting term limits on an agenda (yet not necessarily passing that agenda – merely putting it up for a vote).